# How C++ do overload resolution for this "vector[0] = 1;"

Tags: c++, standards

As I know, C++ only have function overload base on the parameter or implicate object parameter. But I find there are two operator[] for vector. And it will select the correct function in following code:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v[0] = 1; // This will select the non-const version.
return &v[0]; // This will select the const version.
```

Can anyone explain how this happen?

```
      reference operator[] (size_type n);
const_reference operator[] (size_type n) const;
```

------Edit 1------

I think it will select the const version, because following cc file cannot compile with clang++ and g++ with following error. Doesn't understand following error. Can anyone explain more?

> error: cannot initialize return object of type 'char *' with an rvalue
>   of type
>         'const value_type *' (aka 'const char *')
>           return data_.size() == 0 ? NULL : (&data_[0]);

```
#include <assert.h>

#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <map>


class X
{
public:

    X() {
    }

    virtual ~X() {
    }

    char* data() const {
        return data_.size() == 0 ? NULL : (&data_[0]);
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return data_.size();
    }


private:
    std::vector<char> data_;
};
```

Comment: Both select the non const version.

Comment: Why do you think `&v[0]` selects the const version?

Comment: Your edit uses the `const` version because the `data` function is marked `const`.

Comment: Ugh that is a completely different question, you should have asked the question that way in the first place.

Comment: @TartanLIama Oh, I see. Any reference from the standard to talk about this?

Comment: Expanding on what TartanLlama said: ZijingWu's original assumptions about why the const vs. non const were selected are incorrect.  It has nothing to do with what is done with the result of `operator[]`.  It depends on whether the reference to the vector is const.  In the example the reference to the vector is const because it is referenced as a member within a const member function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually in both cases the non-`const` version is called. The time when the `const` version would be called would be if the `vector` was `const`.

```
std::vector<int> const v = {1,2,3};
int x = v[0];
```

In the above case, trying to invoke the non-`const` version would result in a compiler error

```
v[0] = 5;   // nope can't call non-const version, this is trying to mutate a const variable
```

**Edit**
Regarding your example, based on the signature of your function

```
char* data() const
```

you have declared that the method `data` is `const`, meaning that *it shall not attempt to mutate any of the member variables*. In other words, all member variables within a `const` function are treated as `const`. In the context of a `const` method, the variable is seen as

```
std::vector<char> const data_;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `v` is a non-const `vector` the `const`version is never called.